# Same virtual (global) directory for multiple websites

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, virtual-directory

I am working on multiple websites in asp.net mvc. Some websites are top level domains and some are subdomain but all these websites are hosted on same server.

> www.foo.com
>
> subfoo.foo.com
>
> www.abc.com
>
> a.abc.com

I want all these websites should access same directory for save and retrieve some files in this way i can manage files efficiently.

> www.foo.com/assets
>
> subfoo.foo.com/assets

Currently every website is handling data its own wwwroot directory so when i need these files on different website then i have to do lot of work for retrieval.

For this purpose i have created folder out side the websites directory and point out as virtual directory in one websites. I tried to repeat same process for other websites but can 't do this because hosting server does not permit me to point out virtual directory on same folder.

So my question is this limitation of IIS. Is there any other technique to do this task in better way?

Answer (score 0):

Virtual directory is the only way I know of to do what you ask. It sounds odd that you have a limitation of one virtual directory pointing to the same folder, maybe you need a new host.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Just realized how old this question was. Well maybe this will still be of help to someone.....

We run IIS with Approx 5 different web sites. These websites each have their own root directory. We don't typically access things from the other websites, but if we were to do this I would think we would setup another directory on the server for those files to live in. This is assuming that the files you are trying to access are static files.

To Clarify...

C:\inetpub\WebSite1Root
C:\inetpub\WebSite2Root
C:\inetpub\WebSite3Root

Then place the static files in
C:\StaticFiles

So to access those static files Website1 (or 2 or 3) would simply look in that shared directory.

I'm not sure if this helps but I would be happy to answer questions if you have any.